# How to pass options to a jar file using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, parameters, jar

I need to be able to pass option flags to Java when my users execute a given Jar file.  I am using Netbeans as my IDE and it would be nice if I could set it somewhere inside there to avoid manually changing each jar file to do this.

I know under the project if you right click, go properties, then run, you can set options there but I don't believe it builds it into the distributable jar file.

Please note I am NOT asking how to read parameters passed to the jar program itself, I need to pass options to Java.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of options you are trying to pass to java?

Comment: Sure - pretty much anything in `man java` such as -Xincgc

Comment: The only significant options I know you can bundle into an executable jar (as run through java -jar) are specified in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF; they are: Main-Class and Class-Path. Full info is available at http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fd is correct.  The options read out of a jar and applied to the JVM being launched are pretty minimal... but there may be another way to approach this.

You can use the [javaws](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) command to read a JNLP file that will create a JVM that is much more customized.  If your users will have access to a common site, you can probably just distribute the jnlp file and let javaws handle accessing the jar file for your app.  If users will not have access to a common server, you will want to distribute both files (jnlp and jar) and let them install them together.